# Does kri'at shmaʿ on its own require handwashing?

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing, shema

If one is going to recite kri'at shmaʿ on its own (in order to recite it in its proper time), do you need to wash your hands first specially for the purpose? I.e., you're going to be davvening shaharit with a minyan that will miss the latest time, so you're reciting it on your own beforehand. Or, you davvenned ma'ariv with a minyan that prays before nightfall, so later you're reciting kri'at shmaʿ on your own.

Comment: [Brachot 15a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=15&format=pdf) but [Rambam, Hilchot Kri'at Shema 3:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2103.htm#1)

Comment: DoubleAA, is there a scenario on that page where kriat shma is not followed by tefillah?

Comment: He says he curses someone who looks for water to wash for just Shema, but for Tefila it's fine. (Note there are Girsa issues and different understandings. But that's the starting point.)

Comment: DoubleAA, but that's a situation where you don't have water, and would have to spend time looking - what about the default situation where you're at home and have water available?

Comment: I said it's a starting point. You could understand like that and conclude, like it seems the rambam above did, that if you have water you should use it. Perhaps you might also understand the gemara is similar to the one (Chullin 106a) about washing for fruit being מגסי רוח and think it should never be done. The ShA TTBOMK never mentions a requirement to wash for Shema.

Comment: Okay, thanks DoubleAA. I guess maybe the nos'ei keilim of the Rambam for the halakhah you referenced might have some more information.